# Version 11 handles ListPlot PlotRange differently

Tags: plotting

I am having an issue with defining the `PlotRange` of `ListPlot` to be arbitrarily small.  If the `PlotRange` interval is less than one part in $10^6$ of the data values, `ListPlot` will revert to `PlotRange -> All`.  This was not a problem for version 10.4, but I am seeing it for version 11.1.

Example:

(*If I set the range to be 3, it will comply.*)

```
test = {2.0000001*10^6, 2.0000002*10^6, 2.0000003*10^6};
ListPlot[test, PlotRange -> {2*10^6, 2.000003*10^6}]
```

[image: PlotRange works]

```
(* If I set the range to be 2, it will not comply, and instead sets PlotRange -> All. *)

test = {2.0000001*10^6, 2.0000002*10^6, 2.0000003*10^6};
ListPlot[test, PlotRange -> {2*10^6, 2.000002*10^6}]
```

[image: PlotRange fails]

Answer (score 4):

You can translate the data with `ScalingFunctions` so that the "origin" is in the data/plot range:

```
test = {2.0000001*10^6, 2.0000002*10^6, 2.0000003*10^6};
ListPlot[test, PlotRange -> {2*10^6, 2.000002*10^6}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {# - 2.*^6 &, # + 2.*^6 &}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't solve the underlying problem, but should be usable as a workaround:

```
Show[ListPlot[test], PlotRange -> {2*10^6, 2.000002*10^6}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 2*10^6}]
```

`AxesOrigin` is set because this is apparently also messed up.

Output:

[image]